# Can I name an anonymous array in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $aref = [1, 2, 3];
my @a = @$aref;              # this line
$a[1] = 99;
print "aref = @$aref\n";
print "a = @a\n";
```

produces output:

```
aref = 1 2 3
a = 1 99 3
```

The output shows that `@a` and `@$aref` do not refer to the same array.

The marked line is where my problem lies. The value of scalar `$aref` is a reference to an anonymous array. In the marked line I was hoping to be able to make the array variable `@a` refer to that array, but what happens is that the anonymous array is copied and `@a` refers to a copy of the anonymous array. The assignment and print statements show this.

I understand that when you assign to an array the right hand side of the assignment is a list context, so the `@$aref` is coerced to a list of its elements. Is there a way to give the name `@a` to the array referred to by `$aref`?

Comment: What's wrong with just using `@$aref`?

Comment: You can make `@a` a reference, `my $a = $aref`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot - I could just use @$aref. In fact I think I have to. But that does not answer the question!

Comment: @Håkon Hægland - $a and @a are two different variables. How does what you suggest affect @a?

Comment: @NormanofAnstruther That's why I left a comment, not an answer. You can often get better answers if you explain *why* you want to do something instead of just how you want to do it.

Comment: it doesn't; he's suggesting you not use @a.  despite the alias suggestions given in the answers, that is really your best option.

Comment: OK, I get the hint! I will not even try to do this, but will use @$aref instead. My reason was that I thought it would make for simpler code.

Comment: @NormanofAnstruther: Remember that you generally don't want to refer to the entire array. Individual elements can be referred to as `$aref->[1]` etc.. The old-fashioned way is `${$aref}[1]` (bad) or `$$aref[1]` (worse). Also note that `use warnings` is superior in every way to `-w` on the command line or shebang line

Comment: I think this feels like an xy problem.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder *why* would you want to do this? I presume it's a performance issue, but the usual solution is to pass your data around by reference. It is just as easy to write `$aref->[1]` as `$a[1]`

You could *alias* your reference in the package symbol table by assigning to the typeglob, but the alias must be a package variable

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $aref = [1, 2, 3];

our @a;
*a = $aref;

$a[1] = 99;

print "aref = @$aref\n";
print "a    = @a\n";
```

#### output

```
aref = 1 99 3
a    = 1 99 3
```

There are a number of modules that offer a nice syntax and allow you to alias lexical variables

Here's a version that uses [`Lexical::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lexical::Alias) which has the advantage of aliasing lexical variables, and could be more robust than assigning to typeglobs. [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) works in a very similar way. The output is identical to the above

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Lexical::Alias qw/ alias_r /;

my $aref = [1, 2, 3];

alias_r $aref, \my @a;

$a[1] = 99;

print "aref = @$aref\n";
print "a    = @a\n";
```

an alternative way is to use `alias` instead of `alias_r` with

```
alias @$aref, my @a;
```

Comment: absolutely avoid using the first suggestion in this answer; there is no good reason to use a non-lexical variable when you don't have to.

Comment: @ysth: I think *absolutely avoid* is a little strong. Package variables have lexical scope, and need not be visible everywhere. I wouldn't be certain of choosing a module over, say `{ our @a; *a = $aref; $a[1] = 99; say "@a"; }` if it was necessary. Furthermore there is no choice of lexical identifiers when it comes to subroutines

Comment: package variables have lexical scope?  that is false.  the lexical alias `our` creates is lexical, but the data is still global with all the potential for clobbering that brings.  perl 5.18 introduced (experimental) lexical subs; it's something that people have wanted for a long time.

Comment: @ysth: Yes, of course. But I would prefer to put the blame on fully-qualified identifiers than on package variables themselves. I very rarely see package variables qualified with their package name, but then I also rarely see them scoped correctly. Sadly the same applies to lexical variables

Comment: You are addressing a side point, not the main point. `{ our $a; $a .= "a" } { our $a; $a .= "b"; print $a }` prints "ab", not "b", as does  `sub foo { our $a; $a = "ab" } { our $a; $a = "b"; foo(); print $a }`.  Global variables are a problem even without fully qualified identifiers because _they are not scoped_.

Comment: @ysth: I'm addressing *your* point. It is up to you whether you label it a *side point*. And you know very well that global variables are scoped -- you even said so earlier, and `{our $a = 99} print $a` demonstrates it. Please try to restrict your comments to topics that will help the community. Occasionally declaring a variable with `our` as necessary never caused any grief if it was done with regard to scope, and it fills a hole in Perl 5. It is fair to discourage the use of `our` and of package variables, but your ***absolutely avoid*** is silly

Answer (score 6):

1. ```
   our @array; local *array = $aref;
   ```

   Pros: Built-in feature since 5.6.

   Cons: Ugly. Uses a global variable, so the variable is seen by called subs.
2. ```
   use Data::Alias qw( alias );
   alias my @array = @$aref;
   ```

   Pros: Clean.

   Cons: This module gets broken by just about every Perl release (though it gets fixed quickly if not before the actual release).
3. ```
   use feature qw( refaliasing );
   no warnings qw( experimental::refaliasing );
   \my @array = $aref;
   ```

   Pros: Built-in feature.

   Cons: Requires Perl 5.22+, and even then, the feature is experimental.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Borodin's answer, I've tested this with the [Lexical::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=Lexical%3A%3AAlias) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Lexical::Alias 'alias_a';

my $aref = [1, 2, 3];
my @a;
alias_a(@$aref, @a);
$a[1] = 99;
print "aref = @$aref\n";
print "a = @a\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [`Data::Alias`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Alias) package from CPAN.

This way you can write:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Data::Alias qw( alias );

my $aref  = [1, 2, 3];

alias my @a = @$aref;

$a[1] = 99;
print "aref = @$aref\n";
print "a = @a\n";
```

A related question on SO can be found here: [Assign address of one array to another in Perl possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12958962/assign-address-of-one-array-to-another-in-perl-possible)