# Perl: alias an array to an array_ref

Tags: arrays, perl, alias

I would like to do:

```
$array_ref = [ 1, 2, 3];
alias @array @$array_ref;
$array[0] = 4;
# $array_ref->[0] should now be 4
```

In other words: I have a reference to an array, but I would like to address it as if it was a normal array.

**Background**

This is a for a potential extension of GNU Parallel. In GNU Parallel the user can submit a perl expression to be evaled on the internal data structures. Accessing the array of the args is cumbersome to say the least, so I would like to make it possible simply to use @arg instead.

Comment: *"Accessing the array of the args is cumbersome to say the least"* I don't see what's cumbersome about `$array_ref->[0]`, `@$array_ref`, and @{$array_ref}[0,2,4]`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12959090/4248931

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Data::Alias](http://search.cpan.org/~zefram/Data-Alias-1.18/lib/Data/Alias.pm) does what you're looking for.

```
use Data::Alias;
my $array_ref = [1, 2, 3];
my @array;
alias @array = @$array_ref;
$array[0] = 4;
print $array_ref->[0];
```

Output: 4

Comment: Is there a module that does not require a C-compiler (i.e. no .xs)?

Comment: I don't know. Check out serenesat's comment on your question.